# Difference b/w default init-method and beanpostprocessor

Tags: spring

I know this question has already been asked but i didn't get the answer in those posts.I have started reading spring.Before coming to BeanPostProcessor i have gone through default init-method attribute in  tag.

both can be applied as common method to multiple beans defined in the xml.
It'll be good if someone can explain with example.

Answer (score 1):

A `BeanPostProcessor` as the name states is a processor that goes through the context and processes the beans after they are instantiated at two different points: after and before initialization. The init-method is the code that will be executed between the after and before initialization `BeanPostProcessor` methods.

The BeanPostProcessor is a more general implementation of something that needs to be done over beans in the Spring context, a sample of post processing is the `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` that will wire among others the fields annotated with `@Autowired` in the bean being processed.

From javadoc of `BeanPostProcessor`:

> Typically, post-processors that populate beans via marker interfaces
>   or the like will implement postProcessBeforeInitialization, while
>   post-processors that wrap beans with proxies will normally implement
>   postProcessAfterInitialization.

From javadoc of `InitializingBean` (simmilar to init-method, just with the init-method you could choose the method, by passing its name, to be executed for initialization):

> Interface to be implemented by beans that need to react once all their
>   properties have been set by a BeanFactory: for example, to perform
>   custom initialization, or merely to check that all mandatory
>   properties have been set.

In order to facilitate the understanding here is a small Spring sample that will help you out:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SmallSpringTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SmallSpringTest.class, args);
    }

    @Bean(initMethod="doInit")
    public MyClass myClassInstance() {
        return new MyClass();
    }

    @Bean
    public BeanPostProcessor myBeanPostProcessor() {
        return new MyBeanPostProcessor();
    }

    public static class MyClass {
        public void doInit() {
            System.out.println("INITIALIZING BEAN!");
        }
    }

    public static class MyBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

        @Override
        public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
            System.out.println("before init of: " + beanName);
            return bean;
        }

        @Override
        public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
            System.out.println("after init of: " + beanName);
            return bean;
        }

    }

}
```

As you can see we have a init-method configured for out `MyClass` bean. Additionally we have a `BeanPostProcessor`, that will have its after and before methods invoked for each bean on context. The output will be more or less like:

```
before init of: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.MessageSourceAutoConfiguration
after init of: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.MessageSourceAutoConfiguration
before init of: messageSource
after init of: messageSource
before init of: myClassInstance
INITIALIZING BEAN!
after init of: myClassInstance
before init of: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationPackages
after init of: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationPackages
before init of: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration
after init of: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration
before init of: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration$ObjectMappers
before init of: jacksonObjectMapper
after init of: jacksonObjectMapper
after init of: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration$ObjectMappers
before init of: mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter
after init of: mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter
before init of: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration
after init of: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration
before init of: messageConverters
after init of: messageConverters
```